# How to get access from the dictionary to the other method?

Tags: c#

How to get access from one method to another? Here is a Dictionary Products in AddProduct() method, it contains some data and later there will be added some new data.
The method CheckProcutList() shows all products, what were added to Dictionary.
To check product list in one method there is no problem, but how it make separately?
In two words how to make Products global viewed?

```
       public static void AddProduct()
        {
            var Products = new Dictionary<string, decimal>()
            {
                {"Apple Juice", 2.5M},
                {"Pizza", 16.7M},
                {"Cheese Cake", 4.5M},
            };

        }
        public static void CheckProcutList()
        {
            foreach (var kvp in Products) //Here is a problem
                Console.WriteLine("Product name: {0}, Price: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

            SwitchMenu();
        }
```

Comment: `Products` is a local variable of the `AddProduct` and cannot be accessed from outside. You can make it a class field or property.

Comment: or make the dictionary an output of the first method and an input of the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `Products` variable outside of the `AddProduct` method to make it accessible to other methods inside that class and also make it static because essentially a static method has no state. Fields  declared in a non-static manner are essentially like a state, therefore it can't access them.

```
        public static Dictionary<string, decimal> Products;
        public static void AddProduct()
        {
            Products = new Dictionary<string, decimal>()
           {
              {"Apple Juice", 2.5M},
              {"Pizza", 16.7M},
              {"Cheese Cake", 4.5M},
           };

        }
        public static void CheckProcutList()
        {
            foreach (var kvp in Products) //Here is a problem
                Console.WriteLine("Product name: {0}, Price: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

            SwitchMenu();
        }
```

Comment: Why `public`? Why `static`? This doesn't teach the OP absolutely nothing. Whenever they face the same problem they're just going to copy this without understanding at all the implications of what they're doing.

Comment: After I placed a question, I thought "why I did not make a dictionary outside the method", but Ran already answered on my question. Here was one more answer, It was correct too, I dont know, why it was deleted. As I created a class and put there both methods. I did it earlier but had a problem to call the functions, I dont know why, but I forgot that I have to call class first and than a function in the class class.function(). 
Camilo, I know the difference between public, private, protected and what means static. honestly all my methods and function at the moment are public static.